# Reduce ios Native App size which contains audio files

Tags: ios

We have developed an ios app through HTML, CSS, JQuery mobile and converted to Native App through PhoneGap Framework. The app has audio and text, user will navigate to different chapters and each chapter has corresponding songs included in it.

Our app size is 80MB and this is because of large audio files(in mp3 format) within it. 
Audio Files: 78MB
Source Files: 2MB

We want to reduce the size of app for easier download and there is maximum limit of 50MB for OTA update.

what are the ways in which we can reduce app size.

Comment: Encode mp3 at lower bitrate, or mono, or both.

Comment: @Almo - why isn't that an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Good point Dean. Just seemed too short.

Answer (score 2):

1) You could get the app to download all audio content the first time it runs (though this would make the first user experience of the app rubbish).

2) You could stream the content from the web when the app needs it (i.e. the first time the user asks for a chapter). You then cache it so the next time it's played it can play the local file. This means that the app needs a network connection the first time the user views a new chapter.

3) Do what @Almo's comment says. This means your app will download over 3G but if you might lose audio quality.

4) Suck it up and only let users download the app over wifi. Put a comment at the top of your iTunes description saying something like 'Because of the high quality of audio this app is only available over WiFi'.

Comment: +1 from me. #4 is probably a good idea as well, if high-quality audio is important to your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the MP3s at a lower bitrate, or in mono, or both. There's not much else to be done given your setup, without doing something more drastic.

Drastic measures include:

- Removing some of the MP3s.
- Streaming the music over the web.